# What is meant by starting order of the threads?

Tags: multithreading, synchronization

I thought starting order meant the predetermined order of the threads ( at what moment thread X will run), but I started realizing it didn't make any sense, because native threads can't be predetermined.

Isn't the running order of the native threads determined by the operating system and therefore random? I don't understand why we're talking about starting order if everything is "random" or rather determined by the operating system's scheduling service.

Comment: If you want us to explain what someone meant by something, you have to give us their comment in context. You're asking us what someone or something meant by "starting order of the threads" without giving us any context. They could have meant anything by that.

Comment: Can you offer a bit of context for this?

Comment: ah, i just wanted to know what stating order meant generally speaking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When we do not care about the order of execution of certain blocks of statements in a computer program, that is the situation in which we can think about using threads. Code that uses threads, but expects them to execute in a particular order, is usually broken. If it ensures that threads execute in a certain order, then it's wasting the power of threads.

There are no absolutes; there are probably situations in some real-time programming where some select actions have to be done in order, and the most convenient way is to keep those actions in their associated threads (for reasons of context or whatever).

Another example is the use of priority. Priority is a tool that we use when we still don't care about specific orders of execution, but we want more important actions to complete ahead of less important actions, in cases where there is a scheduling conflict.

Comment: is there a default starting order, because I only see like 10 withdrawals and each run a thread which loops 5 times.

Comment: @fogofwar If you have a single CPU, and numerous threads are created or made runnable at the same time, there will be some de facto order in which they are scheduled. For instance, suppose they all have the same priority, and the OS sticks them into the tail of a queue. One thread can rapidly create a bunch of others, which get queued in the order of creation, and then they initially get dispatched in that order.

Comment: Last question, can you determine the starting order of the threads just by looking at the code? If so, what are the rules/steps needed to determine it?